# I pass an anonymous function f = @(x) x.^2 to a MatLab class, but then it disappears?

Tags: matlab

I have a class Solver:

```
classdef Solver
    properties
        myFunc      
    end

    methods
        function setMyFunc(this, myFunc)
            this.myFunc = myFunc;
        end
    end
end
```

I create an instance of this class and then pass it an anonymous function like so:

```
f = @(x) x.^2;
solver = Solver();
solver.setMyFunc(f);
```

If I debug the code and print the 'this' variable inside the setMyFunc method I get the following:

```
Solver with properties:
  myFunc: @(z) x.^2
```

However when the code exits back to my main file and I print the solver variable this time I get:

```
Solver with properties:
  myFunc: []
```

And so clearly it has lost the reference to the function I passed it. What is happening here, how can I pass an anonymous function to a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab strictly uses the pass-by-value convention. The only exception is when  you derive from the handle class. If you do not want to derive from the handle class you need to do

```
methods
    function this = setMyFunc(this, myFunc)
        this.myFunc = myFunc;
    end
end
```

and use it with

```
solver = solver.setMyFunc(f);
```

Since this is a bit awkward, so I would use the following (standard way)

```
methods
    function this = set.myFunc(this, myFunc)
        this.myFunc = myFunc;
    end
end
```

Using this property set method you can actually write

```
solver.myFunc = XXX;
```

to involke the set function.  Note, that in both cases you need `this` also as output argument.

Answer (score 1):

using  `classdef Solver < handle` worked for me:

```
classdef Solver < handle
    properties
        myFunc;    
    end

    methods
        function setMyFunc(this,myFunc)
            this.myFunc = myFunc;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: sorry, it was another thing... the `< handle`. edited my answer